# $T^2=O$ and if $\dim V=2$, $T^2=O$ ($T\neq O$), then $\ker T=\mathrm{Im \;} T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension over field $F$ and $T$ is linear mapping on $V$. Prove that
>
> 1. If $\ker T=\text{Im } T$, then $\dim V$ is even.
> 2. If $\ker T=\text{Im } T$, then $T^2=O$, $O$ being zero operator.
> 3. If $\dim V=2$, $T^2=O$ with $T\neq O$, then $\ker T=\mathrm{Im \;}T$.

**Attempt**:

$\ker T=\mathrm{Im\;} T \implies \dim \ker T=\dim \mathrm{Im\;} T$. Then $$\dim \ker T+\dim \mathrm{Im\;} T=\dim V \implies 2 \times \dim \ker T=\dim V$$ So $\dim V$ is even.

Please help me to show the remaining parts.

Comment: Since $\ker T=\mathrm{Im\;} T$, isn't it true that $T=O$?

Comment: I agree with Jimmy.

Comment: Also, I assume that the assumption $\ker T= \mathrm{Im} T$ does not apply to question 3. since this is exactly what you are asked to show in 3. Right?

Comment: @JimmyR. Consider the matrix $T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, it satisfies $\ker T = \operatorname{im} T$ but it's not the zero matrix.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yeah, right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ii) just note that $ Tx\in Im(T)=Ker(T) $ implies that $ T(T(x))=0$, i.e., $ T^2 (x)=0$, then $ T^2=O $.

For iii) we have $Im(T)\subseteq Ker(T)$ because $T^2=O$, so we can view $Im(T)$ as a subspace of $Ker(T)$. Now, since $T\neq O$, then there is some $Tx\neq 0$ such that $Tx\in Ker(T)$, so $dim(Ker(T)), dim(Im(T))>0$. This together with $dim(Ker(T))+dim(Im(T))=dimV=2$ lead us to $dim(Ker(T))=dim(Im(T))=1$, hence by a well-known result we have $Ker(T)=Im(T)$.

Comment: What is $x$?  Do you mean $x\in V$=domain and do you mean  $Tx$ is same as $T(x)$?

Comment: Yes, $ x\in V $ and $ Tx=T (x) $.

Comment: Why you have deleted part 3

Comment: Because it's not clear what are you asking. You wrote $ Ker (T)=Im (T) $ in the hyphotesis and then you want to prove that (?).

Comment: The question is: Let V be a vector space of finite dimension over field F and T is linear mapping on V. If $\dim V=2$ and $T^2=O$ with $(T\neq O)$, then show that  $\ker T=\mathrm{Im \;}T$

Comment: @user1942348 I edited your question. Now part iii) should be more clear.

Comment: More simply, $\dim\operatorname{im}T>0$, so it is either $1$ or $2$. But $\dim\operatorname{im}T=2$ implies $\dim\ker T=2$, so $T=O$: contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Second one : $T^2 x=T(Tx)$. If $Tx$ is in image of $T$, $T^2 x=0$ by ker$T$=Image$T$($Tx$ is in kernel). Even if $x$ is in kernel, $T^2 x=0$. Done.

Third one : Since $T$ is not equivalent to zero matrix, Image of $T$ is not trivial, so that the dimension of Image $\geq$ 1. And also, from $T^2=0$, Kernel of $T$ is not trivial which also means that the dimension of kernel of $T$ is $\geq$ 1.
So, dim(ker$T$)=dim(image$T$)=1